# IOS PWA FCM notification - onMessage never called, onBackgroundMessage always called

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

Im currently trying to figure out what can and cannot be done within a PWA as of now (Nov 23) on IOS. I've started testing out FCM notifications, with a PWA installed to the home page and I have notifications being displayed in the operating system - which feels like a great start. However i'm noticing that when the application is open these notifications do not trigger the onMessage event on the page, meaning that I cannot update the display within the already open application. I can't see any errors on the console. I've also noticed that onBackgroundMessage is in the service worker is always called. Code is all based around the FCM quickstart example.

Service Worker looks like this

```
// Import and configure the Firebase SDK
// These scripts are made available when the app is served or deployed on Firebase Hosting
// If you do not serve/host your project using Firebase Hosting see https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup
importScripts('./firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('./firebase-messaging-compat.js');
importScripts('./init.js');

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

// If you would like to customize notifications that are received in the
// background (Web app is closed or not in browser focus) then you should
// implement this optional method.
// Keep in mind that FCM will still show notification messages automatically 
// and you should use data messages for custom notifications.
// For more info see: 
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: './firebase-logo.png'
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

Script on the page:

```
 // Retrieve Firebase Messaging object.
      const messaging = firebase.messaging();
      var reg = null;
      if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener("load", function () {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register("./firebase-messaging-sw.js").then(
            function (registration) {
              
              console.log(
                "SW registration successful with scope: ",
                registration.scope
              );
            },
            function (err) {
              console.log("SW registration failed: ", err);
            }
          );
        });
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
          reg = registration;
          resetUI();
            
          });
      }
      // Handle incoming messages. Called when:
      // - a message is received while the app has focus
      // - the user clicks on an app notification created by a service worker
      //   `messaging.onBackgroundMessage` handler.
      messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
        console.log("Message received. ", payload);
        // Update the UI to include the received message.
        appendMessage(payload);
      });
     function resetUI() {
        console.log("RESET UI");
        clearMessages();
        showToken("loading...");
        // Get registration token. Initially this makes a network call, once retrieved
        // subsequent calls to getToken will return from cache.
        messaging
          .getToken({
            serviceWorkerRegistration:reg,
            vapidKey:
              "[vapidKey]",
          })
          .then((currentToken) => {
            if (currentToken) {
              sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
              updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken);
            } else {
              // Show permission request.
              console.log(
                "No registration token available. Request permission to generate one."
              );
              // Show permission UI.
              updateUIForPushPermissionRequired();
              setTokenSentToServer(false);
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log("An error occurred while retrieving token. ", err);
            showToken("Error retrieving registration token. ", err);
            setTokenSentToServer(false);
          });
      }
```

Any pointers so I can update the display upon receiving a push notification, and only display push notifications if the application is not open would be awesome.

Comment: Same issue here - any solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately not as of yet

Comment: any news ? the code works great on android/desktop-crome and safari. Only ios is broken

Comment: Any updates? I'm faceing the same issue